# How to Prove that these Shapes are not Cyclic Polytopes

Tags: convex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

I want to prove that octahedron and icosahedron are not cyclic polytopes. I need to show that for a cyclic polytope, the number of faces incident to a given vertex varies and depends on a vertex.

I think we can apply Gale Evenness condition here. However, I don’t seem to know how to use this to do the proof. Your help would be appreciated.